# Would Snape have switched sides if Voldemort never attacked Harry and the Potters and instead attacked Neville and the Longbottoms?

Tags: harry-potter, severus-snape

In Deathly Hallows, we learn that Snape switched sides and obeyed Dumbledore once Voldemort started hunting down Harry's mother, Lily Potter.

Evidence is below, from the Deathly Hallows:

> “Severus Snape wasn’t yours,” said Harry. “Snape was Dumbledore’s, Dumbledore’s from the moment you started hunting down my mother. And you never realized it, because of the thing you can’t understand. You never saw Snape cast a Patronus, did you, Riddle?”
>   Voldemort did not answer. They continued to circle each other like wolves about to tear each other apart.
>   “Snape’s Patronus was a doe,” said Harry, “the same as my mother’s, because he loved her for nearly all of his life, from the time when they were children. You should have realized,” he said as he saw Voldemort’s nostrils flare, “he asked you to spare her life, didn’t he?”
>   “He desired her, that was all,” sneered Voldemort, “but when she had gone, he agreed that there were other women, and of purer blood, worthier of him —”
>
> “Of course he told you that,” said Harry, “but he was Dumbledore’s spy from the moment you threatened her, and he’s been working against you ever since! Dumbledore was already dying when Snape finished him!”

So the question is, if Voldemort never had targeted the Potters and instead had targeted the Longbottoms, would Snape have switched sides or would he have stayed aligned with the Death Eaters? Snape was never in love with Neville's mother, so that will not have convinced Snape to switch sides since it was Snape's undying love for Lily that caused him to switch sides in the first place.

Comment: Even without the prophecy, Lily Potter was part of the Order of the Phoenix. So it's kinda inevitable that at some point, her life was going to be threatened/in danger.

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate.